# How do I compose the CoreMidi MIDISendSysex Request in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, coremidi

I'm receiving the error.

> Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to type 'MIDICompletionProc'
>   (aka '@convention(c) (UnsafeMutablePointer) ->
>   ()') in coercion.

Everything else looks OK but for the life of me I can't seem to compose the `CompletionProc` function call.

```
    var mySysExSendRequest : MIDISysexSendRequest
    let myCompProc = sysexCompletionProc (a separate static function)

    mySysExSendRequest = MIDISysexSendRequest(destination: Dest,
                                                  data: dataptr,
                                                  bytesToSend: 16,
                                                  complete: complete,
                                                  reserved: res,
                                                  completionProc: sysexCompletionProc as MIDICompletionProc,
                                                  completionRefCon: nil)

    MIDISendSysex(&mySysExSendRequest)
```

Comment: Please show the actual declaration of `sysexCompletionProc`.

Comment: Hi @Alnitak, its just a stub at this stage.

static func MyMIDICompletionProc()->Void {
          print("In MyMIDICompletionProc")
     }

Answer (score 1):

You're currently supplying a function that takes no arguments, i.e. `() -> Void`.

Your completion proc must have this signature:

```
(UnsafeMutablePointer<MIDISysexSendRequest>) -> Void
```

Also note that since the proc has to be compatible with `@convention(c)` semantics it cannot be a class method or a closure.

It may be possible to work around that restriction by passing a pointer to `self` in the `completionRefCon` field and then casting that back (using "unsafe" methods) within the callback.

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak. MIDISysexSendRequest requires a pointer to the itself as a parameter. How do I obtain a pointer to the mySysExSendRequest before it is initialised? Seems like chicken and egg as I need the pointer to be able to initialise?

Comment: @Jon hmm, good point.  It appears to be possible to construct the object using `nil` for the value and then reassign `req.completionRefCon = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(&req)` but I suspect that that pointer is not guaranteed to remain stable over its lifetime :(